# Case bulk delete error

Tags: bulk-api, bulk-delete

I am trying to bulk delete cases where for some case I am getting this error

> "UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION:An unknown exception has occurred.:--"

I checked for all dependancies and found only CaseHistory have some record where CaseId is present, as CaseHistory is the read-only object so not able to delete anything from CaseHistory.

Anybody have any knowledge what wrong I am doing ?

Kind Regards

Comment: What is the full error that you are getting ? Is it only 'UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION:An unknown exception has occurred.:--' ?

Comment: yes, the error message is "UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION:An unknown exception has occurred.:--"
no further informations.

Comment: Try putting a debug log before deleting the cases and see if you can find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe parent/child case relationships are blocking the bulk delete.

Try starting with the cases that have no children (you'd need some additional logic to find that out), or sort by parent case before deleting (leaving the ones without parent case for last).

Comment: If I delete a case individually using workbench I am able to delete, but using bulk delete it returns UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION:An unknown exception has occurred.:--"
I am using bulk delete for some other objects it works fine but only Case giving this problem.

Comment: Yes but even in bulk delete you can sort. Even if you select a large amount of records, it will be split up in batches of 200 for execution. Now if any parent is being deleted before their children, it might result in an unexpected error.